# What do I pass through JNA if the c method requests a file pointer?

Tags: c, jna

So I have a c library method like so:

```
void foo (FILE *out_file, some_struct *struct_ptr, int i);
```

Assuming function foo only uses out_file as output, the c call example given is:

```
foo(stdout,struct,1)
```

What do I pass into JNA as a FILE* pointer? I get that the JNA class declaration would be

```
public void foo (Pointer *out_file, Pointer *struct_ptr, int i);
```

but how do I get Pointer *out_file to print to stdout, or even to a file?

Comment: maybe call another C function that returns a File pointer? fopen()?

Comment: `fopen()` (see [the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) with related functions) is the easiest way to get a file pointer.  If you want `stdout`, you'll have to look at your platform definition of that symbol.  Sometimes it's a macro, sometimes it references an element of a global array, sometimes it's an inlined function.

Comment: @technomage: Mind to make this an answer? I'd upvote it :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fopen()` (see the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) with related functions) is the easiest way to get a file pointer. If you want stdout, you'll have to look at your platform definition of that symbol. Sometimes it's a macro, sometimes it references an element of a global array, sometimes it's an inlined function.